# É possivel selecionar placa de vídeo?

Tags: php, java, jquery, actionscript-3, adobe-air

Estou querendo criar um pequeno programa web onde necessito selecionar uma placa de vídeo.

É um software para exibir musica em projetor. Como o PC terá duas placas uma será somente para mostrar no projetor.

Agora que são elas:

- O sistema precisa ser Web porque será vinculado a um projeto existente.
- É possível fazer essa mágica...rsrsrs?

Essa é uma versão windows, mas a ideia é similar, onde esta em vermelho não irei usar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu sistema tem mesmo todas essas tecnologias que você marcou nas tags?

Comment: Eu *acho* que entendi sua pergunta porque já passei por uma situação parecida. Estou considerando que você precise fazer um sistema que rode num browser, mas que será executado em um computador específico que você controla. E precisa que a imagem ou parte dela apareça num monitor específico (esqueça a placa de vídeo, o sistema operacional abstrai cada saída como um monitor/display). Me corrija se alguma dessas premissas estiver errada.

Comment: Nesse caso você pode usar um browser que te dê mais controle das coisas, em vez de um browser comum. Eu já fiz coisas parecidas com sucesso usando o [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/tree/master) (que é um frankenstein de webkit com node.js)

Comment: @bfavaretto Exatamente isso. To pensando em várias alternativas. Pode ser um programa feito em java instalado no PC, mas só poderia ser acessado se for pelo sistema online. Um actionscript que funcionaria de forma similar. Indica algum material online para que eu possa estudar?

Comment: Deu uma olhada no node-webkit que eu indiquei? Ele tem uma API em JavaScript que permite controlar muita coisa. Por exemplo, você pode criar uma janela sem bordas do tamanho do monitor de destino, e posicioná-la nesse monitor.

Comment: @bfavaretto To olhando agora. Obrigado, qualquer novidades posto aqui :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Não estou sabendo usar o termo certo para achar o que preciso. Seria "video projector" mesmo? Achei esse site [Npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com) tem vário modulos, qual desses seria o que preciso?

Comment: Acho que basta você posicionar a janela na coordenada certa: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Play-with-window. Configure as duas telas como um único desktop estendido, lado a lado, e posicione a janela no ponto onde começa a tela do projetor.

Comment: Mais detalhes: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window

Comment: E ainda: https://github.com/zcbenz/nw-sample-apps/tree/master/frameless-window

Comment: Ta bem difícil de conseguir algum material específico. To procurando até agora. Os link que mandou não serviram.

Comment: @bfavaretto Você saberia fazer isso? Quanto me cobraria?

Comment: Só para constar. Com Flash Player creio não ser possível, a única ferramenta que disponibiliza isso é a classe `Screen`, que só é compatível com Adobe AIR Desktop. Agora, você pode tentar a classe `Capabilities`. Com ela você tem a resolução da área de trabalho atual, assim como os DPI, proporção de pixels, etc.

Comment: @Tiago Não posso fazer por encomenda, já estou com excesso de trabalho...

Comment: Como sugeriu o @biio, realmente o AIR é uma boa opção também.

Comment: @biio Quanto você me cobraria para fazer isso? Atualizei o post com uma imagem.

Comment: Desculpe-me @Tiago, infelizmente já estou com 2 projetos grandes na minha agenda, não posso forçar mais.